# How to set correct Selenium host for nightwatch e2e test on gitlab?

Tags: selenium, vue.js, gitlab-ci, nightwatch.js, vue-cli

I would like to add some e2e tests for my vue.js application and run them in the pipeline.
The corresponding part in my gitlab-ci.yml looks like this:

```
e2e:
image: node:8
before_script:
  - npm install
services:
  - name: selenium/standalone-chrome
  alias: chrome
stage: testing
script:
  - cd online-leasing-frontend
  - npm install
  - npm run test:e2e
```

And my nightwatch.js config:

```
{
  "selenium": {
    "start_process": false
    },
  "test_settings": {
    "default": {
      "selenium_port": 4444,
      "selenium_host": "chrome"
    }
  }
}
```

Is “selenium_host”: “chrome” the correct way of setting the host to the selenium service?
I get the following error indicating that my e2e test can’t connect to the selenium service:

Connection refused! Is selenium server started?

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that according to [this issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/2229), Gitlab CI is using the `Kubernetes Executor` instead of the `Docker Executor` which is mapping all Services to `127.0.0.1`. After setting the `selenium_host` to this address, everything worked.

```
{
  "selenium": {
    "start_process": false
    },
  "test_settings": {
    "default": {
      "selenium_port": 4444,
       "selenium_host": "127.0.0.1",
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the Selenium Repo it says: 
"When executing docker run for an image with Chrome or Firefox please either mount -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm or use the flag --shm-size=2g to use the host's shared memory." 
I don't know gitlab-ci so well, but I'm afraid it is not possible to add this as parameter to a service.